# If A and B are candidate keys, then AB is candidate key or not ?

Tags: database-design, primary-key, relational-theory, dependencies

If R{abc} is a relation, f{ a->b b->a a->c b->c }, then a and b are candidate keys. What about ab ? Is it a candidate key or is it a super key or both ?

Answer (score 2):

The union between A and B is a superkey.

(A candidate key is a superkey but a superkey could be not a candidate key)

Moreover, remember that a **candidate key is a particular type of superkey**, so you shouldn't worry about if it is "both" key and superkey.